# Odd sequence in alternating series test proof

Tags: sequences-and-series

The author of [this article](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/AlternatingSeries.aspx) ([click here for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Karg.png)), when proving the alternating series test,  computes the limit of the odd sequence as follows:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}s_{2n+1}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(s_{2n}+b_{2n+1}\right)$$

$$\dots$$

How is $s_{2n+1}=s_{2n}+b_{2n+1}$?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The **definition** of the notation $s_n$ at that reference is
$$s_n=b_1-b_2+b_3+\cdots+(-1)^{n-1}b_n$$
Therefore
$$\begin{align*}
s_{2n}&=b_1-b_2+b_3+\cdots-b_{2n}\\
s_{2n+1}&=b_1-b_2+b_3+\cdots-b_{2n}+b_{2n+1}
\end{align*}$$
so that
$$s_{2n+1}=s_{2n}+b_{2n+1}$$

Comment: Isn't $ s_{2n}=s_{2n−2} +b_{2n-1}-b_{2n}$?

Answer (score 1):

By definition, $s_{k}$ is the sum of the first $k$ terms in the sequence: $$ s_{2n+1} = \underbrace{ \ b_1 - b_2 + \dots + (-1)^{2n+1} b_{2n} \ }_{= \ s_{2n}} + \underbrace{ \ (-1)^{2n+2} b_{2n+1} \ }_{= \ b_{2n+1}} $$